# Automating online job application systems (applicant tracking software) is legal?

Tags: common-law, corporate-law

Application tracking software or job application software is annoying most of the time. They ask you to fill out loads of information along with your resume, even if your resume has most of it. People tend to apply hundreds of jobs, especially college graduates. So I was wondering if I somehow automate this system, So my software (or mobile app or chrome extension) will fill out this information automatically, Is it legal?

I'm asking this because they ask you to enter "FULL NAME" (as e-signature) and "DATE" as part of:

- Disability agreement
- Veteran status
- Other racial information etc.

This information is taken in almost all of the applicant tracking software out there. Please advise.

Comment: I would assume it's perfectly legal, assuming the information is filled out correctly. If the information is not filled out correctly, I wouldn't see it as different from regular human error while manually filling out the form - and I doubt that's a crime. It might cause headaches if it fills out wrong information that gets interviews denied or offers rescinded, but I can't see legal troubles there. I don't even think it's illegal to intentionally lie on a job application, unless it's for the government... then you had better have the user double check it. IANAL. What's your jurisdiction?

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That's good to hear. My jurisdiction is GA, USA.

Comment: No problem - I'm not knowledgeable enough to post a real answer. I suspect the employer will typically have more bargaining power in most of these cases and my very limited understanding is that *caveat emptor* applies - it's up to them to make sure they're getting the right stuff from you if they care about it.

Comment: If you are making an app then your jurisdiction is not just GA, USA; it is wherever the app is used.